# Search for a pattern and replace the 6th delimited word with another pattern, say delimiter is ";" (Semicolon), and in-file editing is preferred

Tags: unix, solaris

Example file having 6 columns with ";" separator:

```
temp;abcd;YES;1234;pqrs;YES

aaaa;bccc;YES;1234;pqrs;YES

ramy;uqq;YES;adda;1234;YES
..

..

..
```

Now Search for multiple patterns(pattern to be searched can be 1 or more) say temp and bccc, and replacing the 6th(**or the last**) delimited word with NO, in the line that matched the pattern.

i.e expected output should be

```
temp;abcd;YES;1234;pqrs;NO

aaaa;bccc;YES;1234;pqrs;NO

ramy;uqq;YES;adda;1234;YES

..
..
..
```

It would be really good to have in-file editing, as I would be using the code in a **recursive** loop, where multiple patterns to be searched would be dynamically assigned in a shell variable.

Something like this:

```
var='temp|abcd'
```

`grep $var filename |` based on pattern matched, replace the 6th or last work with a NO, with file having a ; delimiter.

Comment: I tried the below but got errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to do it with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)!

Say your data is in `a.txt` file, and you write a small piece of code `a.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { OFS=";" ;  FS=";" ; print "start\n---------------" }
{
  if ( $0 ~ var )
  { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"NO" }
  else
  { print $0 }
}
END { print "---------------\nend" }
```

- NB1: interesting trick in here [is how to pass a `shell` variable to hawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script).
- NB2: also note how you use `~` to parse the [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) inside `var`
- NB3: there is much useless code above, but it is good to understand how `awk` works: 3 parts, the middle part being repeated for each line of your input file.

Then you can call your code like below:

```
awk -f a.awk -v var="abcd|temp" a.txt
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
 awk -v var="abcd|temp" -F";" \
 '{ if($0~var){print $1";"$2";"$3";"$4";"$5";NO"} else {print} }'  a.txt
```

To understand more about it, here is a [great tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: Wow, Thanks so much, You made my day!!! I will just give it a try today or tomorrow, and will mark your answer as complete.

Comment: Just tried this and get the below error, this is on Unix Solaris just for your information.                                                                                   Can you please help me on what mistake i am doing?                                                       > awk -f ../Scripts/a.awk -v var="DEU0194|DEU0197|DEU0198|DEU0366" Reported.csv
awk: syntax error near line 4
awk: illegal statement near line 4
awk: syntax error near line 6
awk: illegal statement near line 6

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have `solaris` here to try scripting. From the line number it looks like the `~`might be an issue.  [Here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/120324-deleting-last-n-lines-output.html) someone suggest using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` ... do you have it installed? Do you still get same error if you replace `~`with `=`?

Comment: Thanks, yes had the /usr/xpg4/bin/awk installed. :) This works, Only thing is, if there is any option to update the file inline would have been good, as i mentioned i would like to use this with in a recursive loop, so it would be a bit bad to put it into a temp file everytime. If possible, and you get to know about infile editing you can let me know. However, this returns the expected output, So thanks for that again.

Comment: Happy to read it works for you. Now, about recursion, I know it's always possible to replace it with  a `while` loop. Since `a.awk` uses `var`, it's kind of dynamic. And yes with this technique you must do the changes over and over on a temporary file.

Comment: Yes, i tried it and it perfectly works :) Thank for your solution!